# backup restore all ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, backup-restoration

I need to change my server(all hardware). I`m running Ubuntu-server on it. I use it for LAMP. Is there any way to completely backup running server and restore it on another(all of databases, Mysql users,configurations,databases,Apache configurations,network,...)?
I can stop my Apache, Mysql for limited time.

Comment: Please see this answer :

http://serverfault.com/questions/328071/linux-migration-from-a-server-to-another/328119#328119

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mondorescue.org/

this is the ONLY solution available, that supports HOT Backup of online system.

Mondo Rescue is a GPL disaster recovery solution. It supports Linux (i386, x86_64, ia64) and FreeBSD (i386). It's packaged for multiple distributions (RedHat, RHEL, SuSE, SLES, Mandriva, Debian, Gentoo).

It supports tapes, disks, network and CD/DVD as backup media, multiple filesystems, LVM, software and hardware Raid.

Otherwise, CloneZilla can be used if you can turn off server for some time.